# differential eq. model

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm studying some population models for fun and came across this particular remark

> Consider the differential equation
>   $$\frac{dx}{dr}= ax-bx^2, \quad x(r_0)=x_0$$
>   the solution is given as $$x(r)=\frac{a}{aD_1e^{-ar}+b}.$$
>   The limiting value as $r\to\infty$ is $a/b$ and if $x_h$ is the time from which 1/2 the limiting value is achieved then $$x(r) = \frac{a/b}{1+e^{-a(r-r_n)}}$$
>    I'm not sure how to prove the result containing $x_h$. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2):

once you have $$x(\infty) = \frac ab,\, x(0) = \frac a{a+D_1}$$ you can find the $r$ so that $$x(r) =\frac 12  x(\infty)=\frac a{2b} = \frac{a}{aD_1e^{-ar}+b}$$ that gives you $$ 2b = aD_1e^{-ar_h} + b,\,aD_1 = be^{ar_h}.$$ 
putting this in the original equation gives you $$x(r) = \frac{a}{e^{-a(r-rh)}+b} $$

Comment: You are too fast for the old man !! Cheers :-)

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici, it is good to meet on these pages again.